# Como converter ícones .svg em uma fonte?

Tags: css, svg, css-font-face, font

Existe uma forma recomendável para converter e combinar vários ícones no formato `.svg` em um único arquivo de fonte (`ttf`, `woff`, etc)?

Quero definir uma `@font-face` e atribuir minha fonte, de modo que eu possa usar seus ícones da mesma forma que se usa por exemplo no "Font Awesome", atribuindo uma classe ao um elemento `<i>`:

```
<i class="meu-icone"></i>
```

Comment: E por que se dar o trabalho? Por que não usar o SVG mesmo? Se for por compatibilidade, o suporte dos dois é mais ou menos o mesmo. Mas se quiser mesmo tem ferramentas online que fazem isso pra ti

Comment: @Costamilam Sei que posso usar direto todos `.svg`, mas gostaria de aprender como é feito isso.

Comment: @ThiagoKrempser eu prefiro utilizar como `font` do que imagem, eu utilizo o **IcoMoon** para gerar o `@font-face` dos `SVG's` os quais faço upload do mesmo. Caso você ache que a minha resposta foi adequada para a sua pergunta, é só marca-la com o "check verde".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar uma maneira simples para isto, a qual é a seguinte:

- Um sistema pronto para esta conversão denominado [IcoMoon](https://icomoon.io/).

**Sobre o IconMoon**

> A biblioteca de ícones do **IcoMoon** apresenta apenas os melhores ícones definidos lá. Todos os nossos ícones são projetados em uma grade de pixels precisa. O aplicativo **IcoMoon** permite que você crie e use seus próprios pacotes de ícones em diversos formatos, incluindo `SVG`, `Polymer`, `PDF`, `XAML`, `CSH`, fonte de ícone com ligaduras ou boas sprites `PNG/CSS` antigos.

**Nota**

> Caso você queira criar um ícone personalizado e que o mesmo não existe na internet, utilize um software denominado [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/pt-br/). Após criar a vetorização gráfica do ícone, você deve salvar em `SVG` e utilizar um sistema como o citado acima para fazer a conversão de `SVG --> font + @fonte-face`.

Comment: Como criar uma fonte no Inkscape? Fiquei curioso, uso a ferramenta, mas não sabia que dava pra fazer isso

Comment: Inkspace salva em TTF ou OTF ou coisa do tipo? Até onde sei ele não salva nem exporta fontes... https://inkscape.org/pt-br/aprender/faq/#quais-sao-os-formatos-que-o-inkscape-pode-importarexportar

Comment: @Costamilam como você não citou que sabia criar os vetores e com o Inkscape, eu citei o mesmo para você, caso você quisesse criar algo personalizado. Por resumo o Inkscape só cria os vetores mesmo, ele não exporta/salva em fontes, você teria que criar os icones lá em SVG e converter em um sistema como o IconMoon.

Comment: @hugocsl Isto é verdade, eu respondi acima para ele.

Comment: Sugiro remover essa parte da sua resposta, já que está errada, pra não confundir ninguém

Comment: @Costamilam alterei a resposta, para ficar mais clara e objetiva.